# how to dismiss loader on Ionic4

Tags: typescript, ionic4

i am not able to dismiss the loader pragmatically.

i created two methods. one for presenting the loader and another for the dismiss  and call them accordingly when required.

```
async loaderPresent() {
    this.loader = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: "Please Wait"
    })
    await this.loader.present();
  }

  async loaderDismiss() {
    this.loader = await this.loadingCtrl.dismiss();
  }
```

i don't want to dismiss the loader by implying duration as a option.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `this.loader.dismiss()` as this.loader is the variable which holds your loader.

Answer (score 0):

```
async loaderDismiss() {
   await this.loader.dismiss(); 
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the OPs question, it is recommended that you include a bit of context (why the original code didn't work, why this technique is better etc.) so that you have a bit more than a code only answer and the OP or future users won't have to ask for more context if there is something unclear.